# Validating admission webhook based on client source IP

Tags: kubernetes

We would like to implement a validating admission webhook that allows or denies requess based on the client source IP, but in the `AdminissionReview` object, the IP is not available.

Using `--requestheader-extra-headers-prefix` it is possible to inject the IP into the `admissionReview.Request.UserInfo.Extra` map, but this is only suitable when using an external authenticator. It doesn't work when using the builtin authentication methods of Kubernetes, e.g. the OIDC authenticaton.

When the Api Server calls the admission webhook, it doesn't seem to provide any additional headers or other information that could be used.

Comment: How would you manage client source IP handling within external authentication tool?